# Are installed npm packages for dependencies and devDependencies present in node_modules dir

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-managers

When I run npm audit, I see number of critical issues for ex: @angular/compiler-cli is listed in devDependencies.

```
  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         tar                                                           

  Patched in      >=2.2.2 <3.0.0 || >=4.4.2                                     

  Dependency of   @angular/compiler-cli [dev]                                   

  Path            @angular/compiler-cli > chokidar > fsevents > node-pre-gyp >  
                  tar                                                           

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/803
```

I want to fix this issue , when I try to access @angular/compiler-cli inside node_modules, I don't find this package, though I have already ran npm install many times.

Let me know if dependencies and devDependencies are present in same node_modules

Answer (score 0):

I don't think people should fix these issues in the node_modules or anywhere else in their local projects. Ideally the two options for fixing issues like this are clone the repo they come from, fix the issue and submit a merge/pull request and/or changing the version that you are using to one that doesn't have the error. With that being said, I think that dependencies are in node_modules.